# Uploading multiple files using Django & React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and React for my recent project. I need to upload multiple images/files from my React frontend to the Django REST backend. I'm not sure which is the efficient way to do it.

1: Looping over each selected image/file using React and sending them one by one to the backend.
2: Accepting multiple images/files from the frontend, and looping through each image/file, and saving it in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make Another `Model` for uploading multiple photos and file like :-

**models.py**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    another_model = models.ForeignKey(User*,on_delete=models.CSCADE,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
    file = mdoels.FileField()
```

You have to make a typical form and a view to upload `File` and `Photo`.

***Note** :- You can also change `ForeignKey with` **User**. You can ForeignKey with another Model( if you're connecting with it any ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, And yes I've created a separate model and its corresponding views. Is it better if I receive the array of images and iterate through them in the backend or do it in the frontend? which is better incase of the site's performance?